# Nested option in select

Tags: php, arrays, nested, html-select

I'm making a taxonomy system. I already created my recursive function and also a function to display my categories in a list (`<ul>`). Everything works fine with the list, every child element is move to the right...etc...

But now I need to do the same with a `<select>`. Here is what I've done so far :

```
private function _toHtml(&$list, $parent=-1, $pass = 0){
    $foundSome = false;
    for( $i=0,$c=count($list);$i<$c;$i++ ){
        $delay = '';
        if( $list[$i]['parent_id']==$parent ){
            if( $foundSome==false ){
                $delay .= str_repeat("--", $pass);
                $foundSome = true;
            }    
            echo '<option value="'. $list[$i]['id'] .'">'. $delay . $list[$i]['name'] .'</option>';
            $this->_toHtml($list,$list[$i]['id'],$pass+1);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, this works only on the first child elment, the others are kind of not considering at all. It looks basically like that :

```
Cinema
--English (sub cat for Cinema)
French (also a sub cat for Cinema)
```

When I expect to have :

```
Cinema
--English (sub cat for Cinema)
--French (also a sub cat for Cinema)
```

Any idea?

Thanks for your help

Comment: http://dipesharea.wordpress.com/2011/06/03/n-level-category/

Comment: How many levels do you have? Should parent be chosen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you face such problems, get more straight forward and forget about any premature optimization. Simplify your function by reducing nesting and proper naming of variables.

```
private function _toHtml($list, $parent = -1, $level = 0)
{
    foreach ($list as $entry) {
        if ($entry['parent_id'] != $parent) {
            continue;
        }
        printf('<option value="%s">%s%s</option>',
            $entry['id'],
            str_repeat('--', $level),
            $entry['name']
        );
        $this->_toHtml($list, $entry['id'], $level + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: You rocks man, thanks it works perfectly. Also thank you for the simple version of that code. Why doing complicated when we can do it simple? Thanks